# How to fetch albums photos from facebook using fb_graph gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems

I created a photo album on facebook named 'exemple'.
Is it possible to fetch all the pictures links of The album knowing only the name of the album?
How do I proceed with fb-graph gem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
results = FGraph.get('/user_id/albums')
```

user_id can be "me"

Always good to play w/ the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)